# Missing values in shorthand property

Tags: html, css, flexbox, language-lawyer

Quoting [CSS 2.2 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/about.html#shorthand):

> When values are omitted from a shorthand form, each "missing" property
>   is assigned its initial value (see the section on [the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html)).

But how do browsers know which value matches which property? For example, the following code is taken from [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.header, .main, .nav, .aside, .footer {
  flex: 1 100%;
}
```

What does this mean? Is it equivalent to

```css
.header, .main, .nav, .aside, .footer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: initial;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

or

```css
.header, .main, .nav, .aside, .footer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 100%;
  flex-basis: initial;
}
```

or something else?

Comment: I've updated my answer since originally posting as I realised I was wrong about what your example translates to. Your example of `100%` will never be attributed to `<flex-shrink>` as this only accepts *number* values (whereas the `%` makes this a *width* value).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I'm aware of that. Thanks for your nice answer!

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, "whereas the % makes this a *width* value" .... flex-basis can also set height... depends on flex-direction.

Comment: @Michael_B I believe that still counts as a *width* value here; if you have a rectangular cardboard box and you tip it on its side, you wouldn't claim that its width had changed - it'd simply be facing a different direction. *[Tomatoes, tomatoes](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55062/what-does-to-may-to-to-mah-to-mean)*.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, try it out. You might be surprised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Flexible Box Layout Module specification defines how the shorthand property should be handled in its [*The 'flex' Shorthand* section](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property):

```
 Value: none | [ <‘flex-grow’> <‘flex-shrink’>? || <‘flex-basis’> ]
```

Using the [CSS Values and Units specificaiton](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#component-combinators) (which defines what the `|`, `?` and `||` symbols in the above statement mean, we can see that the value should either:

1. Be `none`
2. Be `<flex grow>` (and optionally `<flex-shrink>`) and/or `<flex-basis>` in that order.

This means that your example of:

```css
flex: 1 100%;
```

Translates to:

```css
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: initial;
flex-basis: 100%;
```

Because `100%` is not a valid value for `<flex-shrink>`

If, however, the example was instead:

```css
flex: 1 0;
```

Where `0` is a valid value for both `<flex-shrink>` and `<flex-basis>`, this would translate to:

```css
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: initial;
```

Answer (score 0):

The position of the value determines which property it is being set for. Just like the arguments of a `function()` in PHP.

If you wish to skip the latter properties they will be set to a normal/auto. But if you wish to skip a mid-placed property value you can try setting it to `auto/inherit`. But in CSS if you want to skip a property from a shorthand, the only decent way up until now is to use full form of properties.

Comment: Not fully accurate ...  See example 2 in Donnelly answer

Comment: Generally speaking, using full form of properties should be encouraged, but you'll have to read others' code sometimes and  you cannot force them to do so.